# Software for displaying date time stamps on SONY DCR-SR35 footage

Tags: video, camera

The main problem of modern (or not so modern but still not old) cameras is that they don't record the date and time on the actual video, and i NEED the date and time to be shown.

Is there a software i could use to open Sony DCR-SR35 DVD camcoder footage files and add the date/time stamps to the video and save the files for later editing and production of DVD-Video?

Been searching countless hours on google for an answer with no luck so far.

I have found some plug in for the Sony vegas studio, however, once i loaded the footage file (.mpg), add-on failed to extract the date time from it. I AM sure there is a date and time writen inside the file, how else would Sony camera show the date when replaying the video, right?

The other solutions were 5 years old, and seemed to be geared towards mpeg2 (which is the same thing as this Sony camera produces, right?) but the links were dead :(

Until now, we are using the DVD-Video player/recorder by streaming the sony cameras playback screen to the recorder and writing it to the DVD disk, which i later on copy to PC for editing, splitting, adding titles and menu and so on. TONS of work, LOTS of time taken, especially when this recorder fails to correctly finalize the DVD and it becomes "empty" when inserted into PC.

This is just too much of a frustration. I also found out that the camera does not support USB streaming, so cant connect directly to pc.

Buying another DVD recorder will cost alot, so at this point i am trying to find some kind of software which could work with the mpg files, so i wouldnt even need to stream anything.

If all fails, might as well try and find a Video-in card for a PC, if such things even exist nowadays.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*FFmpeg* has a video filter called drawtext, which you can use in a shell script.  Here's an example, which you can modify to fit your needs.  I am using *ffprobe* to get the file's encode date.  You can choose the text color, font, position, and destination codec.

Keep in mind that in order to composite the text like this, you will be transcoding the video, so it may still be slow, depending on your CPU speed.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter path to movie..."
read -e FILENAME
ENCDATE=`ffprobe "$FILENAME" 2>&1 | grep -m 1 creation_time | awk '{print substr ($0,23,19)}'`
echo $ENCDATE
ffmpeg -i "$FILENAME" -vcodec mjpeg -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/Library/Fonts/Arial\ Black.ttf: text=\'$ENCDATE\': x=.05*W: y=.95*H: fontcolor=white: fontsize=36: box=1: boxcolor= 0x00000000@1" -an -y "$FILENAME"_new.mov
```